# Appearance: Application Style- but that's ALL it shows

Tags: kubuntu, kde

Under "appearance," the only thing that shows is *Application Style/Window Decorations*.

[Icon View,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmHxV.png) [Sidebar View,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSdhk.png) [and Tree View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhyFe.png)

Comment: You're missing other stuff as well! In Workspace, you don't have Search. In Personalization, you don't have Notifications and Accessibility. In Network, you don't have Connectivity or Bluetooth ….